# Generate resources for compile and test

Tags: scala, sbt

I intend to generate resources based on templates and sbt settings. There should be different sbt settings for `Compile` and `Test`. The templates are in `project/resources/hdfs/*.xml`. From the sbt-dev gitter chat, I've had the recommendation to use `Setting` and `inConfig`, but I couldn't get it to work.

Code so far:

```
val hdfsNamenode = settingKey[String]("Namenode for the HDFS access")

def genHdfsConfigs: Setting[_] =
  hdfsNamenode := {
    resourceGenerators += Def.task {
      val files = ((baseDirectory.value / "project" / "resources" / "hdfs" ) * "*.xml").get
      files.foreach({ hdfsTemplate =>
        val config = IO.read(hdfsTemplate).replace("{{namenode}}", hdfsNamenode.value)
        IO.write(resourceManaged.value / hdfsTemplate.getName, config)
      })
      files.toSeq
    }.taskValue
  }

hdfsNamenode in Test := "localhost"
hdfsNamenode in Compile := "172.31.32.228"

def allHdfsNamenodeConfigs: Seq[Setting[_]] =
  inConfig(Compile)(Seq(hdfsNamenode)) ++ inConfig(Test)(Seq(hdfsNamenode))
```

Errors:

```
[error]  found   : sbt.Def.Setting[Seq[sbt.Task[Seq[java.io.File]]]]
[error]  required: String
[error]       resourceGenerators += Def.task {
[error]                          ^

[error]  found   : sbt.SettingKey[String]
[error]  required: sbt.Def.Setting[_]
[error]     inConfig(Compile)(Seq(hdfsNamenode)) ++ inConfig(Test)(Seq(hdfsNamenode))
[error]
```

Next iteration, I don't know how to get the `hdfsNameNode` in scope `Compile`/`Test` instead of unscoped.

```
lazy val hdfsNameNode = settingKey[String]("Namenode for the HDFS access")

val genHdfsConfig = Def.task {
  val files = ((baseDirectory.value / "project" / "templates" / "resources" / "hdfs" ) * "*.xml").get
  files.map({ hdfsTemplate =>
    val config = IO.read(hdfsTemplate).replace("{{namenode}}", hdfsNameNode.value)
    val outputPath = resourceManaged.value / hdfsTemplate.getName
    IO.write(outputPath, config)
    outputPath
  })
}

Seq(
    hdfsNameNode := "undefined", // Only this one is accepted
    hdfsNameNode in Test := "localhost",
    hdfsNameNode in Compile := "172.31.32.228",
    resourceGenerators in Compile += genHdfsConfig.taskValue,
    resourceGenerators in Test += genHdfsConfig.taskValue
  )
```

Current (ugly) solution:

```
val hdfsTestNameNode = "localhost"
val hdfsMainNameNode = "172.31.32.228"

val hdfsNameNode = settingKey[String]("Namenode for the HDFS access")

val genTestHdfsConfig = Def.task {
  val files = ((baseDirectory.value / "project" / "templates" / "resources" / "hdfs" ) * "*.xml").get
  files.map({ hdfsTemplate =>
    val config = IO.read(hdfsTemplate).replace("{{namenode}}", (hdfsNameNode in Test).value)
    val outputPath = resourceManaged.value / hdfsTemplate.getName
    IO.write(outputPath, config)
    outputPath
  })
}

val genCompileHdfsConfig = Def.task {
  val files = ((baseDirectory.value / "project" / "templates" / "resources" / "hdfs" ) * "*.xml").get
  files.map({ hdfsTemplate =>
    val config = IO.read(hdfsTemplate).replace("{{namenode}}", (hdfsNameNode in Compile).value)
    val outputPath = resourceManaged.value / hdfsTemplate.getName
    IO.write(outputPath, config)
    outputPath
  })
}

Seq(
  hdfsNameNode in Test := hdfsTestNameNode,
  hdfsNameNode in Compile := hdfsMainNameNode,
  resourceGenerators in Compile += genCompileHdfsConfig.taskValue,
  resourceGenerators in Test += genTestHdfsConfig.taskValue
 )
```

Comment: This thing with `Def.task` and `.taskValue` looks complicated for me. Perhaps that was needed for older sbt versions? Have you looked at http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Custom-Settings.html#Implementing+a+task - it should be as simply as as `taskKey` and  a `:=`.

Comment: @0__ then I don't know how to add it to the `resourceGenerators` so it gets picked up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just pass the Configuration as an argument when you define your resource generator.

```
val hdfsTestNameNode = "localhost"
val hdfsMainNameNode = "172.31.32.228"

val hdfsNameNode = settingKey[String]("Namenode for the HDFS access")

def genHdfsConfig(cfg: Configuration) = Def.task {
  val files = ((baseDirectory.value / "project" / "templates" / "resources" / "hdfs" ) * "*.xml").get
  files.map({ hdfsTemplate =>
    val config = IO.read(hdfsTemplate).replace("{{namenode}}", (hdfsNameNode in cfg).value)
    val outputPath = (resourceManaged in cfg).value / hdfsTemplate.getName
    IO.write(outputPath, config)
    outputPath
  })
}

Seq(
  hdfsNameNode in Test := hdfsTestNameNode,
  hdfsNameNode in Compile := hdfsMainNameNode,
  resourceGenerators in Compile += genHdfsConfig(Compile).taskValue,
  resourceGenerators in Test += genHdfsConfig(Test).taskValue
)
```

Don't want to specify the scope twice? Just refactor a bit more.

```
val hdfsTestNameNode = "localhost"
val hdfsMainNameNode = "172.31.32.228"

val hdfsNameNode = settingKey[String]("Namenode for the HDFS access")

def addHdfsConfigGenerator(cfg: Configuration) = {
  inConfig(cfg) {
    val hdfsConfigGenerator = Def.task {
      val files = ((baseDirectory.value / "project" / "templates" / "resources" / "hdfs" ) * "*.xml").get
      files.map({ hdfsTemplate =>
        val config = IO.read(hdfsTemplate).replace("{{namenode}}", (hdfsNameNode in cfg).value)
        val outputPath = (resourceManaged in cfg).value / hdfsTemplate.getName
        IO.write(outputPath, config)
        outputPath
      })
    }
    resourceGenerators += hdfsConfigGenerator.taskValue
  } last
}

Seq(
  hdfsNameNode in Test := hdfsTestNameNode,
  hdfsNameNode in Compile := hdfsMainNameNode,
  addHdfsConfigGenerator(Compile),
  addHdfsConfigGenerator(Test)
)
```

Comment: I was hoping there would be a way without having to specify the scope twice.

Comment: I was looking for a more sbt-refactoring solution, but this works just as well.